# Why is this Random Forest perfect?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm learning Random Forest Classifier from a video, where the instructor got a score of 0.44, while I'm getting 0.9985 ( But actually it's perfect). Did I overfit it? If so what is the next step? Shouldn't it 'forget' and 'relearn' every time I compile the code again?
Please check the code below:

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


bird = pd.read_csv('image_attribute_labels.txt', sep= '\s+', header=None,
        error_bad_lines=False , warn_bad_lines = False,
        usecols= [0,1,2], names =['imgid', 'attid', 'present'])


bird2 = bird.pivot(index = 'imgid', columns= 'attid', values ='present')


imglbl = pd.read_csv('image_class_labels.txt', sep=' ', header=None, names= ['imgid', 'label'])


imglbl =imglbl.set_index('imgid')

#merging the two arrays
df= bird2.join(imglbl)
#Shuffling the array
df= df.sample(frac=1)

df_att = df.iloc[:,:312]
df_lbl = df.iloc[:,312:]

#choosing the train and test data
df_train_att = df_att[:8000]
df_train_lbl = df_lbl [:8000]
df_test_att = df_att[8000:]
df_test_lbl = df_lbl[8000:]

df_train_lbl = df_train_lbl['label']
df_test_lbl = df_test_lbl ['label']

clf= RandomForestClassifier(max_features=50 , random_state= 0, n_estimators= 100)
clf = clf.fit( df_train_att, df_train_lbl)

print(df_train_lbl.head())
print(clf.predict(df_train_att.head()))
score = clf.score (df_train_att, df_train_lbl)
print (score)
```

The output for three times was as follow:

1:

```
imgid              #]
4499     78        #|
7442    127        #|
3200     56        #| The actual data
7271    125        #|
2601     46        #]
Name: label, dtype: int64
[ 78 127  56 125  46] # The predicted ones
0.99875 # The score
```

2:

```
imgid
10982    187
11632    198
1536      28
5449      94
8503     145
Name: label, dtype: int64
[187 198  28  94 145]
0.9985
```

3:

```
imgid
6782     116
10906    186
2465      43
6660     114
9257     158
Name: label, dtype: int64
[116 186  43 114 158]
0.9985
```

Comment: you never use the test data, also there is probably something wrong with how your read in the data because you have approximately index*58=label?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of this:

```
print(clf.predict(df_train_att.head()))
score = clf.score (df_train_att, df_train_lbl)
```

better try this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
test = clf.predict(df_test_att)
score = accuracy_score(test, df_test_lbl, normalize=False)
```

Comment: OK, so my mistake was using the train data again instead of the test ones. The output of the `accuracy_score` was approx. 1700, is this the number correct predictions? and one more question, the program really 'forgets' everything after it exits, right?

Comment: 1700 is something strange i would say. You should get a score between 0 and 1. The program forgets everythings since all variables are in ram. You need to save your model to a file if you want to keep changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the RandomForestClassifier *max_depth* parameter to something other than *None* (small integer value). When using *None* the nodes are expanded until all leaves are pure so you perfectly fit the train dataset. Other option is to calculate your score using [cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).